# Menu item still visible even though alterRoutes denies access to it

Tags: routes, 9

I have the following RouteSubscriber in a custom module:

```
namespace Drupal\frilaering_access\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

    if ($route = $collection->get('user.logout')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_access', 'FALSE');
    }

    //THIS ONE STILL APPEARS IN THE MENU FOR SOME REASON
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.user.edit_form')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_access', 'FALSE');
    }

    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.user.canonical')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_access', 'FALSE');
    }
  }
}
```

And although access is denied the link to the user edit page is still visible in the menu. The other 2 menu items are hidden as they should be.

Any idea why this is not working for the user.edit_form?

EDIT - here is my subscriber:

```
services:
  frilaering_access.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\frilaering_access\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Can you show us the route definition in your routing.yml?

Comment: Thanks - added now. But as I say, the alters are working - the requirements are set. But the menu item for user/edit stays visible

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just discovered that the "Edit user" link is provided by the module "User current paths", so the solution was to use the route "user_current_paths.edit_redirect".